# Equivalent Java data type to hold the Informix DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND value?

Tags: java, jdbc, informix

I wanted to map the Informix DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND to a Java data type.

Can someone give the corresponding Java data type to hold the Informix **DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND** value?

---

This is the answer: **java.sql.Time** according to my JDBC driver.

Comment: You need to know what your JDBC driver maps in Java. I suggest you try it and find out the type.

Comment: Informix JDBC Driver maps java.sql.Timestamp to the Informix type
DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(5) and java.sql.Time to the Informix type
DATETIMEHOUR TOSECOND. InformixDATETIME types are very restrictive and
are not interchangeable. If you attempt to bind java.sql.Time to DATETIME YEAR
TO FRACTION(5) or java.sql.Timestamp to DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND, you
might get an error from the Informix database server. Any other DATETIME quali-
?ers are not supported.

Comment: Thanks @peter for pointing out right direction :-)

Comment: You wrote that driver you use maps this to `java.sql.Time` but driver I use: JDBC.3.70.JC1DE maps `DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND` into `java.sql.Timestamp`. Maybe you use some old version of Informix JDBC driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made simple test using table from Jonathan Leffler answer to:
 [Informix 7.3 - Declaring a date column data type with default as current date on insert/update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464440/informix-7-3-declaring-a-date-column-data-type-with-default-as-current-date-on)

I use Jython and JDBC Informix driver JDBC.3.70.JC1DE. Test code that uses metadata looks like:

```
    db = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, usr, passwd)
    c = db.createStatement()
    rs = c.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test_datetime")
    rsmd = rs.getMetaData()
    print('columnCnt: %d' % (rsmd.getColumnCount()))
    while (rs.next()):
        for i in range(rsmd.getColumnCount()):
            col_no = i + 1
            print("value: [%s]" % rs.getString(col_no))
            print("name: [%s]" % rsmd.getColumnName(col_no))
            print("Java type: %d" % rsmd.getColumnType(col_no))
            print("Java class name: %s" % rsmd.getColumnClassName(col_no))
            print("column type name: %s" % rsmd.getColumnTypeName(col_no))
            print('-' * 20)
```

Output for interesting columns:

```
value: [03.01.11]
name: [date_column]
Java type: 91
Java class name: java.sql.Date
column type name: date
--------------------
value: [2011-01-03 00:00:00.0]
name: [datetime_yd]
Java type: 93
Java class name: java.sql.Timestamp
column type name: datetime year to day
--------------------
value: [2011-01-03 10:28:51.0]
name: [datetime_ys]
Java type: 93
Java class name: java.sql.Timestamp
column type name: datetime year to second
--------------------
value: [10:28:51]
name: [datetime_hs]
Java type: 92
Java class name: java.sql.Time
column type name: datetime hour to second
```

So correct answer for this version of JDBC driver is: `datetime year to second` is mapped to `java.sql.Timestamp`.

PS You wrote thay your driver maps this to `java.sql.Time` but maybe you use some old version of Informix JDBC driver?

Answer (score 2):

DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND can be mapped to a TIMESTAMP according to this documentation :
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iwedhelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2e.doc/dbsap_b3.html

TIMESTAMPs can be mapped to java.util.Date.
If you need to perform calculation on your Date, use java.util.Calendar:

`Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.setTime(date);

// Use the roll fonction to alter the date

// For example add one month to your Date

calendar.roll(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

// Get your Date back

date = calendar.getTime();`

Do you use any framework to map your data ?

Comment: According to this http://www.informix.com.ua/doc/9.30/5343A.pdf  java.sql.Time is the answer

Comment: Dinesh, I tested it and with my JDBC Informix driver JDBC.3.70.JC1DE it is mapped to TIMESTAMP.

Comment: In PDF I have found that `java.sql.Time` is used for `DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND`. When you start with `YEAR` then `java.sql.Timestamp` is used. *Important: Informix JDBC Driver maps java.sql.Timestamp to the Informix type
DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(5) and java.sql.Time to the Informix type
DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [java.sql.Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) ? I have no knowledge of Informix, however it seems to be the natural type for such a data, no ?

Comment: No, A Java SQL Date, like its parent class `java.util.Date`, in fact stores a timestamp, precise to the millisecond. In fact, it's just that the name is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

you can use java.util.Date, if you want to access hour, minute and second values..

Answer (score 0):

yes i got your question .. You can use a `Timestamp` data Type

ex....

```
Timestamp temp;
```

Comment: According to this http://www.informix.com.ua/doc/9.30/5343A.pdf  java.sql.Time is the answer